# Padding each vector in an array of vectors

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, vector

Say I have a numpy array of vectors like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [2,3]..]
```

What is the fastest way to pad each vector in the list with 0s so that each vector has the same length?

Comment: I would recommend the pandas approach, if you have it.

Comment: Find the longest list and add the missing zeros to each sublist. By the way, you do not have an array of vectors. You have a list of lists.

Comment: The "duplicate" solution is order of magnitude slower than a core python-based solution. Pandas/numpy is not a panacea. Sometimes lists are just lists.

Comment: @DYZ The question is tagged numpy...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ But the input is a list of lists. W/e. The OP does not seem to care about proper use of terminology.

Comment: @DYZ If OP confirms they have a list of lists and do _not_ want a numpy solution, I will reopen this. Otherwise, it seems pointless.

Comment: A non-numpy oneliner is: `list(zip(*(itertools.zip_longest(*a,fillvalue=0))))` (py3)